# Customer who has ordered more than once, at least once and not ordered in last 90 days in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

How can I write a formula in MS EXCEL, to know the customers who have bought an item more than once, at least once and not ordered at all in 90 days.
Below How data looks:
Take the order date as B column and the second one as C column.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365:

Get a unique list of customers spilled from `E2` using (for instance):
`=SORT(UNIQUE(C2:C14))`

The get the count through the following in `F2`:
`=COUNTIFS(B2:B14,"<="&MAXIFS(B2:B14,C2:C14,E2#),B2:B14,">"&MAXIFS(B2:B14,C2:C14,E2#)-90,C2:C14,E2#)`

If you don't have Office 365 replace each 3 `E2#`'s in the formula with the customer name you want the result for.

If you also want to show the result for customers unlisted, wrap it in `IFERROR`: `=IFERROR(formula,0)`

[image]

Comment: Hello P.b, is this the answer for ordered more than once or at least once ? Because I have posted 3 questions.

Comment: This is the count of orders of the last 90 days since the maximum date.

Comment: If you want it compared to today, replace the `MAXIFS()`-parts with `TODAY()` and `TODAY()-90`

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but I made a small solution for this which is COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$15,">="&$B$15-90,$C$3:$C$15,H3), I have taken 1 April 2020 as the date, also made another table as Customer1,2,3...6 where H3 is representing Customer 1 and so on. Hope I am clear and it would help many others also.